# How to prevent Visual studio loading dlls from diferent path of his project refrence path

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I've noticed that Visual studio looks for a referenced dll anywhere (other projects, GAC, ...) if that dll isn´t in referenced path. It happens mostly with nugget packages.
Is there anyway to prevent this behavior?

I think this behavior is dangerous, because it gives you false security that your application has all refenreced dlls correctly, at the time of deploy app you can get a surprise.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The .Net Framework does look in the applications directory or subdirectories, GAC and (if deployed to) on http server.

You can find the description [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/assembly-location).

For GAC and http server the framework does require a strong name signing. So if your assembly is not strong signed the framework won't search there.

When deploying an app with release, this normally also should include a test installation on a non-development workstation (where no visual studio or anything else is installed). Additionally, checking that all dependent assemblies are deployed is another task of programming (at least, in my opinion).
Visual studio also does copy referenced nuget packages assembly to the output directory without any manual action.

Comment: Thanks dsdel, but I was asking for any visual studio option that prevents this behavior  so I get compilation error when refreneced dll isn´t in the right place

Comment: This should produce an error. However having the reference in the project of visual studio and the reference when you deploy the release build are different things. Please check if your references have got the 'copy local' attribute set to True.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is not a behavior of Visual Studio but rather of .NET itself. The process of how and where assemblies are resolved is an intrinsic and essential part of the technology. So in my eyes, you are contradicting one paradigm of .NET.

However, you can use a couple of workarounds. [This post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies) contains Microsoft's description of how the .NET runtime locates assemblies. Thus you could try to ship around these manners, e. g. not signing assemblies would skip accessing the GAC.